# read a csv column's color from PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to read only colum with red label in a csv file. Is there a php function to do this or a symfony bundle?
Now I'm reading csv file with **fgetcsv** function:

```
foreach($request->files->get('importFile') as $file) {
    if (($handle = fopen($file->getRealPath(), "r")) !== FALSE) {
        // get the rest of the rows
        $data = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';')) {
            if($i>1) {
                $data[] = $row;
                $i++;
            }

            print_r($data);die;

        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't read the label's color.Is there a way to read the color on the csv files?

Comment: You can't set the color of any row in csv, because csv is simply text based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV files have no formatting.

`.xls` or `.odt` files have formatting, but CSV definitely not - only data are saved in there. Look at the file with a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this php class to read csv files: https://git.webworks-nuernberg.de/webworks-nuernberg/parsecsv

But cweiske is right, csv hasn't any formatting.